# Can't get stock in getStockQty() at app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Block\Stockqty\Abstract.php

Tags: stock

i just found that the `isMsgVisible()` do not get the stock by using `$this->getStockQty()`, the full function are as follow:

```
public function isMsgVisible()
{
    return ($this->getStockQty() > 0 && $this->getStockQty() <= $this->getThresholdQty());
}
```

The `getStockQty()`

```
public function getStockQty()
{
    if (!$this->hasData('product_stock_qty')) {
        $qty = 0;
        if ($stockItem = $this->_getProduct()->getStockItem()) {

            //$qty = (float) $stockItem->getStockQty();
            $qty = (float) $stockItem->getQty();
        }
        $this->setData('product_stock_qty', $qty);
    }
    return $this->getData('product_stock_qty');
}
```

The `$stockItem->getStockQty()` is always return 0, i have to change to `getQty()` to make it works. Is it a bug? i'm not dare to patch to production site now.

Comment: please try this:-$product->getStockItem()->getQty();

Answer (score 0):

Hi check below code may be help you

```
$productId=3;
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$inventory =  Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')>loadByProduct($_product);
echo $inventory->getQty();
```